# I cannot extract and copy data with macros

Tags: csv, macros, imacros

I need to automate a task: copy a cell from a csv file, paste it to google.com/finances search area, get search result, scroll down, copy industry and sector and paste this info to the same csv file next column. This is my first macro. It seems working until extracting info from the web and pasting it to my csv file. Could you please help me with this part? And a couple more questions. How do I avoid throwing an error if google doesn't find any data? How do I avoid throwing an error if it runs into an empty cell?

My macro is bellow:

```
VERSION BUILD=11.5.498.2403
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
SET !PLAYBACKDELAY 0.2
SET !DATASOURCE "C:\\Users\\Agne\\Desktop\\bandymas\\kitas_failas.csv"
SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
URL GOTO=google.com/finance
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=NAME:q CONTENT={{!COL1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON:SUBMIT ATTR=ID:gbqfb
TAG POS=10 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:g-unit<SP>g-first EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER="C:\\Users\\Agne\\Desktop\\bandymas" FILE="kitas_failas.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using two files: 'kitas_failas.csv' as a datasource and 'kitas_failas_ext.csv' for extracted info. So your macro may look like:

```
VERSION BUILD=11.5.498.2403
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
SET !PLAYBACKDELAY 0.2
SET !DATASOURCE "C:\\Users\\Agne\\Desktop\\bandymas\\kitas_failas.csv"
SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
URL GOTO=google.com/finance
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=NAME:q CONTENT={{!COL1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON:SUBMIT ATTR=ID:gbqfb
SET !EXTRACT {{!COL1}}
TAG POS=10 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:g-unit<SP>g-first EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER="C:\\Users\\Agne\\Desktop\\bandymas" FILE="kitas_failas_ext.csv"
```

And in order to ignore errors apply the following command:

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
```